# Storing Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

I have been trying to solve this problem for three days now, it's really simple for those who know the open graph api well. I'm new to Facebook integration but have some PHP experience.

Basically all I'm trying to do is retrieve the following information from users and store it in a database.

Facebook User ID:
Name
Gender
Email

I have done the user ID, name and gender by using:

```
$contents = file_get_contents ('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user);
$json=json_decode($contents,true);
$userid = $json['id'];
$username = $json['name'];
$usergender = $json['gender'];
$useremail = $json['email'];
```

This works and I understand I need to ask for permissions to access the email which I have done using this code:

```
$app_id = "211665122244023";

     $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/midcitymafia/";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
```

But how do I get the access token and then use it to retrieve email from graph?

##UPDATE, THIS IS MY CURRENT CODE, STILL CAN'T SEEM TO GET IT TO WORK...

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$app_id = "211665122244023";

     $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/midcitymafia/";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);


     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
         $graph = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id . "/?accesstoken=" .$data['access_token']));
     }

$userid = $graph->id;
$username = $graph->name;
$usergender = $graph->gender;
$useremail = $graph->email;

?>

<br>

<?php echo 'ID: ' . $userid; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Name: ' . $username; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Gender: ' . $usergender; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Email: ' . $useremail; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signed_request` contains user `access_token` within itself.

In your case `access_token` is in `$data['access_token']`

Storing user `access_token` isn't a best idea since they provided for a short period of time and expired later. To get permanent `access_token` you need to request `offline_access` permission from user (I personally wouldn't recommend it since you may achieve most things without requiring `offline_access`, in many cases Application `access_token` may fit your needs).

Comment: Thanks, now I can't just store that in my database can I? What I mean is, they expire right? How would I go around updating it? I have read the 'revoking page' but don't really understand...

Comment: I now have got to this code ^^ check main post, still don't seem to work.. thanks.